# Converting Dictionary <string , string[]> to Dictionary <string , double[]>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way to convert type of Dictionary to another type of Dictionary?

I want to convert `Dictionary <string , string[]>` to `Dictionary <string , double[]>`

Comment: Iteration should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every element within the string-array can be converted to double you have to convert every element within your map seperately:

```
var result = myDict.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Key,
    x => x.Value.Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(y)).ToArray());
```

To be save when your input-data contains content taht cannot be parsed as double you may also consider use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = myDict.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Key,
    x => x.Value.Select(y => 
    {
        double value = 0;
        Double.TryParse(x, out value));
        return value;
    }
```

We won´t care for the result of `TryParse` here because we set `value` to its default value and return this if conversion fails. However if you want to return another value you should also add an if-statement here and return some different value if parsing fails (e.g. `-1`).

Comment: I would use Double.TryParse method to be safe.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The problem is that it returns a bool, so I cannot directly return this via `Select`-statement. To keap it simple I avoid a block of statements within the select.

Comment: I think there is a little `typo` in your `LINQ` above: `y.Convert.ToDouble(y)` should be `Convert.ToDouble(y)` (without `y` in front)

Comment: Great! ;) it is a nice solution

Comment: i got error message "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate typ"

Comment: @Thatoneguy I already mentioned I wanted to keep it simple. However I´m not sure what you mean with the second part. You have of course to take completely new data-structure, so you can not use the original dictionary any further, if you ment this.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, He could pass in a 'more complex' lambda or function delegate which uses TryParse and returns the value that was parsed or some other sential. The problem I see with this is now its ruined the integrity of the structure and it's no longer 'myDict' as floats but a **subset** of 'myDict' as floats. e.g. If he now used try parse he still has to return something or throw an error anyway. It depends on his use case but a hard failure may be more suitable.

Comment: Do you? For me it works just fine? What is your inout? Can you show how your dictionary looks like?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you and thanks to others guys
it work fine now

Comment: @Thatoneguy I did not mean for the OP to use tryparse within this solution. The OP can use a foreach loop or some other looping construct and use tryparse. If it fails, either catch, ignore and continue or keep track of all the failed ones.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Added a `TryParse`-approach.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You are almost there. However, a zero may mean a valid value in the OPs case and if there is logic written which depends on the value being zero, then there will be issues. Correct way to use tryparse is to check if it was successful. If not, then take measures according to business requirements.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I already considered this, however I - again for the sake of simplicity - ignored this fact and assumed `0` a non-valid. However you´re right, if `0` was valid we had to define some other magic number to indicate an error.